# Quiet boot on raspbian buster

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-buster

I am trying to hide boot up messages on my raspberry PI. I upgraded it from the stock raspbian image to buster via this guide: https://gist.github.com/nickfox-taterli/fcddd0ac724ec066b51f8e777800fea2. Unfortunately since then I cannot figure out how to hide boot messages. I can put it into a different tty using /boot/cmdline.txt but I cannot hide it like I could in raspbian stretch. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the answer help you? if so you should accept it. This will finish the question and it will not pop up again after months.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

**Remove rainbow screen**

in `/boot/config.txt` add `disable_splash=1`

**Overclock the SD Card from 50 to 100MHz**

This can only be done with at least a UHS Class 1 card

```
dtoverlay=sdtweak,overclock_50=100
```

**Set the bootloader delay to 0 seconds. The default is 1s if not specified.**

```
boot_delay=0
```

**Remove icon and cursor**

in `/boot/cmdline.txt`

```
splash quiet plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles logo.nologo vt.global_cursor_default=0
```